# If..else.. with selection box value javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selection box with three different options (4 really with the blank one) and after I click a button I need an alert box to display a message. Here's some code.

HTML:

```
<select id="item1" name="Item 1">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Camera</option>
      <option value="2">Microphone</option>
      <option value="3">Tripod</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="message()">Go!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
    <SCRIPT language = javascript>

function message() {

var s = document.getElementById('item1');
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

if (item1 = 1) {
    alert("it equals camera")
}
else if (item1 = 2) {
    alert("it equals microphone")
}
else if (item1 = 3) {
    alert("it equals tripod")
}
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Every time I click the button the alert box says "it equals camera". I could select Microphone and click the button and it would still say that.

If I put

```
alert(item1)
```

in the function it displays 1, 2, or 3. So I'm assuming it's something with the if..else.. statements.

Answer (score 4):

Remember using `==` instead of `=`

```
if(item == 1)
```

instead of

```
if(item = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript we should use `===`, this *checks data type* also.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (item1 = 1) {
```

with

```
if (item1 == 1) {
```

(and the same for the other ones)

`item = 1` changes the value of `item1` and returns `1`, which evaluates as `true` in a test.

But note that you could more efficiently

- use a switch
- or read the value directly

For example :

```
document.getElementById('item1').onchange = function(){
    alert("it equals " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);        
}​​​​​​​​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/LEKsf/)

Comment: double equals on all three `if`s

Comment: Good gosh! This is more like a chat room! Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (any pretty much every other curly-braces-language) the single `=` always means *assignments*. So you assign the value `1` to `item1`.

You want the *comparison* operator which is `==`.

```
function message() {
    var s = document.getElementById('item1');
    var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

    if(item1 == '1') {
        alert("it equals camera")
    } else if(item1 == '2') {
        alert("it equals microphone")
    } else if(item1 == '3') {
        alert("it equals tripod")
    }
}
```

Here are some other suggestions to improve your code:

- Do not use the deprecated `language` attribute of `<script>`. Just `<script>` is fine for JavaScript or `<script type="text/javascript>` if you want to be explicit.
- Do not use inline events. Instead of the `onclick="..."` register an event handler using the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this method, it's easier when your selector gets more items?

```
var s = document.getElementById("item1");
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
window.alert('it equals '+item1);
```

**Edit:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBSRj/)

**Edit 2:** Changing `=` to `==` solves your problem. And instead of using `s.options[s.selectedIndex].value` you can simply use `s.selectedIndex`. This will also return 1, 2 or 3 and this is easier to understand.